# Catalyst exiting when started with start-stop-daemon

Tags: perl, catalyst, start-stop-daemon

I am trying to run [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) on [CentOS](https://www.centos.org/) 7 using [start-stop-daemon](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html). Here is the `start-stop-daemon` command that I run:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile /var/run/myapp.pid -d "/home/user/myapp" --exec /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.0/bin/perl --startas "/home/user/myapp/script/myapp_fastcgi.pl" --chuid root --make-pid -- "-l :8100 -n 6"
```

Then I get this error:

```
Cannot resolve host name   -- exiting!
```

It displays this error after loading the chained actions and printing them to the screen, and after displaying the final message:

```
[info] myapp powered by Catalyst 5.90112
```

In `/etc/hosts` I've tried commenting out any hostnames I thought might be causing an issue:

```
127.0.0.1 myapp.com myapp.com 
#127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
#127.0.0.1 localhost4.localdomain4 localhost4

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#::1 myapp.com myapp.com
#::1 localhost.localdomain localhost
#::1 localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

What's strange is that if I don't use `start-stop-daemon` and I just start the server from the command-line, the server starts fine.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it can't resolve your hostname.

Check what your `hostname` command returns and make sure that same host name is present in your /etc/hosts. And don't assign it to loopback, use a real IP.

You can also trace what exactly it's trying to resolve by using this method

https://serverfault.com/questions/666482/how-to-find-out-pid-of-the-process-sending-packets-generating-network-traffic

Or might be even more simple to do `tcpdump -s 0 port 53`